# Jquery Slide not sliding

Tags: jquery

My jquery slide is not sliding, it is really just appearing. I can see the animation if I do .show, but I want it to appear from top to bottom. I have tried the following with the same result (just showing up, no animation):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#aboutLink').click(function () {
        console.log("click");
        $('#content').slideDown(3000);
    });

});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#aboutLink').click(function () {
        console.log("click");
        $('#content').slideDown('slow');
    });   
});
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
    min-height:700px;
    margin-left:22px;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="grid_11 content" id="content">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It tries to look for the `height property.`

```
The .slideDown() method animates the height of the matched elements.
```

But you have only defined the `min-height`

Try replacing that with `height : 700px`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ktsw5/)**

Something like this

```
 $('#aboutLink').click(function () {
     console.log("click");
     $('#content').animate({
         height: '400px'
     }, 3000);
 });
```

But for this to work you need to **make sure the element is not hidden on the page**. Otherwise it won't work.

**[Animate Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ktsw5/1/)**

Comment: Ah, that did it. How do I handle wanting it to dynamically change the height though as content fills?

Comment: I think maybe my question was confusing. I don't want to set a hard max-height but rather have it fill out as the content changes in the div. (Some of the div's will be larger than the others)